# Do While Loop Code for Excel Declaration

Tags: vb.net

I have very big excel file takes long time to open.

I want to declare xlApp without error as soon as file is ready.

Following code need to be repaired.

```
Process.Start("C:\Book1.xlsx")
Do While SOMETHING
   Application.DoEvents()
Loop
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
xlApp = CType(GetObject(Nothing, "Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
```

If I run following line without opening Book1 then following line gives error.

```
xlApp = CType(GetObject(Nothing, "Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
```

Using following code is not good idea because opening time of Book1.xlsx always different.

```
 Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
```

Comment: if you're using the `Excel.Application` object anyway, just rewrite to use its `Open()` function, which will open synchronously (return just after the file has been loaded). Also, as it currently stands, I think it is not guaranteed that GetObject would return the same instance that opened Book1.

Comment: I am confused by what you are waiting for. Even if Excel is currently opening a file... you can create multiple instances. Again I am not sure what you would be waiting for.

Comment: @dlatikay My question is not related instance. So please think my question again only one excel instance is running.

Comment: @JohnG I changed my question above for your understanding.

Answer (score 3):

If the file takes long to open, then you just have to wait. But there is something else you can do if that is an option.

Firstly to open the file, use this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workBook =
    excel.Workbooks.Open(fileLocation);
```

For that you just have to wait but the application is created so it is ready as soon as the file is ready.

If the file takes too long to open, what you can do is convert the file into CSV  and save it. Then afterwards, you can read that file whenever you want and you can read it pretty quickly. Again this may not be an option but if it is, then here is how:

```
workBook.SaveAs(
    fileLocation + ".csv",
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows
);
workBook.Close(true);
excel.Quit();
```

Then you can read it really fast using `File.ReadLines()` method. That method will read one line at a time so it will not try to load the whole file but just one line and you can start reading it right away. As you read more lines, it will keep reading them into memory:

```
foreach (var thisLine in File.ReadLines(fileLocation))
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But your answer is not related my question. Please delete your answer.

Comment: Why do you think it is not related to your question? May I know what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @SamSamuel Starting Excel with `Process.Start`, then declaring `Excel.Application` and trying to connect like you are doing does not make sense. This answer is correct.

Comment: @SamSamuel I think this addresses the issues in your approach pretty well, so maybe you did not take the time to read and understand it? It's a good answer and can be useful to other people too.

Comment: This is a good approach and if you're not open to suggestions on changing your approach I wouldn't bother asking questions to be honest.